# Image in UISegmentedControl is blue?

Tags: xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to put an image into the UISegmentedControl item but my image is blue, not show normal ?
This is my code :

```
NSArray *segments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone1.png"],
                         @"iPad",
                         @"iPod",
                         @"iMac", nil];
    self.mySegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segments];
    CGRect segmentedFrame = self.mySegmentedControl.frame;
    segmentedFrame.size.height = 64.0f;
    segmentedFrame.size.width = 300.0f;
    self.mySegmentedControl.frame = segmentedFrame;
    self.mySegmentedControl.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.mySegmentedControl];
```

[image]

The first segment is a iphone image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was an ios7 change. Now `UISegmentedControl` uses the tint color of self to change tint of the image, so you have to render the image in its original mode.

```
UIImage* iPhoneImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone1.png"];
if (//Device is iOS7 or higher) {
    iPhoneImage = [iPhoneImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}

NSArray *segments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     iPhoneImage,
                     @"iPad",
                     @"iPod",
                     @"iMac", nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to set image to Item in UISegmentedControl

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

Comment: I read this function in iOS Developer Library and do it. But it didn't work. Can you explain more ?